# What is the largest positive signed integer that can be stored in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In the Firebase Firestore docs it says https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

> Integer Numeric  64-bit, signed

I would expect the acceptable number range to be -2^63 to 2^64 - 1 inclusive.

The largest positive integer should be (2^63) - 1 = 9223372036854775807. When I use the Firebase console to enter this value into a int field the number appears as is shown as 9223372036854776000. I'm assuming these are two's complement representation.

What have a I missed?

Comment: If this is running on top of JavaScript then it might be doubles under the hood. Does the problem first pop up around `2^53 - 1` (which is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` in JavaScript)?

Comment: @JohnColeman That is indeed the case.